# Node.js server/client module confusion, EventEmitter woes

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, coffeescript, eventemitter

I'm trying to write a library which can be used in Node.js *or* on the client-side.

I'm running into *two* issues:

1. I can't seem to export it correctly. I'm using [this doc](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/syntax/code_reuse_on_client_and_server). `MyClass = exports? and exports or @MyClass = {}` doesn't seem to work, so I split up the files for now.
2. The library emits events; I'm hoping someone can clarify my confusion on how to do this more simply. Follow with me below :)

**Node.js:**

*Library:*

```
    {EventEmitter} = require 'events'

    class MyClass extends EventEmitter

      emitSomething: (key, data) ->

        @emit key, data

module.exports = MyClass
```

*Required:*

```
MyClass = require 'myclass'
myClass = new MyClass()

myClass.on 'someevent', (data) ->
  console.log data 

# Bare with not using `emit` directly.
data = 
  key: 'value'

myClass.emitSomething 'someevent', data
```

**Client-side**

[EventEmitter](https://github.com/Wolfy87/EventEmitter) is included.

```
class MyClass extends EventEmitter

  emitSomething: (key, data) ->

    @trigger key, [ data ] # That's stupid.
```

The library file is included in a script and somewhere I do:

```
myClass = new MyClass()

myClass.on 'someevent', (data) ->
  console.log data 

data = 
  key: 'value'

myClass.emitSomething 'someevent', data
```

**Client-side**

Backbone.js/Underscore.js are included (not the EventEmitter library above).

```
class MyClass

  constructor: () ->

    _.extend @, Backbone.Events

  emitSomething: (key, data) ->

    @trigger key, data # Notice the difference.
```

The library file is included in a script and somewhere I do:

```
myClass = new MyClass()

myClass.on 'someevent', (data) ->
  console.log data 

data = 
  key: 'value'

myClass.emitSomething 'someevent', data
```

So, uh, what's the best way to write a library that emits events for both Node and the browser? The EventEmitter library seemed to conflict with Backbone when I had them both included (it needs to work on Node, and with or without Backbone). There's got to be a simpler solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using browserify, which will let you simply use your MyClass module client side since it includes a version of nodecore events.

So client side:

```
MyClass = require('./myclass')
myClass = new MyClass()
```

http://browserify.org/

https://github.com/substack/coffeeify

Comment: That's really interesting. Let me give that a go and see if it solves my problems :)